# Wordpress redirect to homepage after successfully logged in

Tags: wordpress, authentication, dashboard, wordpress-login

When I try to log in to my WordPress website through /wp-admin, or /wp-login after entering the correct login and password details, it will redirect to the homepage rather than to the dashboard.
I have tried the following:

1. Disable all plugins.
2. Changed theme from generatepress to default wp theme.
3. restore .htaccess file to basic settings.
4. repaired database from wp toolkit from c panel.
5. Delete browser cache (Google Chrome)
6. Checked (go through) the wp-config file code to see any additional code.

I have tried all possibilities one by one and again and again with no result.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an example of what it might look like:

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'custom_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
function custom_login_redirect( $url, $request, $user ) {
    if ( $user && is_object( $user ) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
        if ( $user->has_cap( 'administrator' ) ) {
            $url = home_url();
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Note: You have to put this code into your functions.php

Comment: Thx sir, i have copied/paste the code in the functions.php file of current theme, clear browser history and tried to login but again the same issue. I have also deactivated the plugins, shifted to default wp theme and tried to login but unfortunately could not. My login url is technotrait.com/wp-admin

Comment: @Rafaqat Ali
That's strange because the code should work. I saw that your page is lacking SSL protection. Maybe thatss an issue? Try to make your page available under https://....